# JavaScript Boolean function within an objects properties

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I'm trying to access a boolean value from a method within an obj

Code 1 - error

```
var obj = {
    positionX : 700,
    radius : 10,
    checkRight : function(){
        if (obj.positionX < (canvas.width - obj.radius)){
            return true;
        }
    },
    moveRight : function(){this.positionX += 5;}
};

var Key = {
    right : false
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            Key.right = true;
            break;
    }
};

function keyUpHandler(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            Key.right = false;
            break;
    }
};

function draw() {
    drawObj();
    if (Key.right && obj.checkRight){    // I've also tried if (Key.right && obj.checkRight==true)
        obj.moveRight();
    }
};
```

Code 2 - works but untidy

```
var obj = {
    positionX : 700,
    radius : 10,
    moveRight : function(){this.positionX += 5;}
};

var Key = {
    right : false
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            Key.right = true;
            break;
    }
};

function keyUpHandler(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            Key.right = false;
            break;
    }
};

function draw() {
    drawObj();
    if (Key.right && obj.positionX < (canvas.width - obj.radius)){
        obj.moveRight();
    }
};
```

The idea is that the obj should stop moving to the right when it reaches the edge of the canvas. However with this code, it won't move right at all. But if I put the 'checkRight' code directly into the draw() if-statement it works fine. Does anyone know why it doesn't work as an obj function?

Comment: Its because `obj.checkRight` is a function - but you're not calling it - add the `()` to call it! `obj.checkRight()` - simply running `obj.checkRight` will return the function definition, which is truthy, so `if (obj.checkRight)` will always pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 37 in the section labeled "Code 1" you have:

```
if (Key.right && obj.checkRight) {
```

when it should be

```
if (Key.right && obj.checkRight()) {
```

The former tests the truthiness of the method and will be coerced to `true` since functions are truthy in JS. The latter calls the method and uses the return value in the conditional expression.

Comment: I tried doing this and it prevents the obj from moving right at all

Comment: It turns out this was correct, but I had coded the 'checkRight' function with a > instead of a < operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition, your `checkRight()` method will *never return* if the condition is not met because you only return if the condition is `true`.

There is a better pattern to employ when you have an `if` block that just returns a Boolean based on a condition or set of conditions. Instead of this:

```
checkRight: function() {
    if (obj.positionX < (canvas.width - obj.radius)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Just return the condition itself:

```
checkRight: function() {
    return obj.positionX < (canvas.width - obj.radius);
},
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this approach first but had the same issue as I have now